# With ERC in Emacs, how can I automatically alias server buffer names?

Tags: emacs, irc, elisp

I use ZNC to connect to IRC, and since ZNC seems to have the unfortunate characteristic of making me create a new "login" for each server I want to connect to (i.e Freenode and Quakenet), when erc starts I have a bunch of buffers all named the same thing.

My erc config looks like:

```
(defun djcb-erc-start-or-switch ()
  "Connect to ERC, or switch to last active buffer"
  (interactive)
  (if (get-buffer "example.com:60667") ;; ERC already active?

    (erc-track-switch-buffer 1) ;; yes: switch to last active
    (when (y-or-n-p "Start ERC? ") ;; no: maybe start ERC
      ;; I use ZNC so I need to hit my server
      (erc :server "example.com" :port 60667 :nick "nick1")
      (erc :server "example.com" :port 60667 :nick "nick2")
)))
```

How can I get it to start and alias the server buffer names for `nick1` to `Freenode` and `nick2` to `whateverrandomserver`?

Comment: This should be simple, but ERC is heavily magical around the mode line so it's not; I tried hooking `erc-mode-hook` and renaming the buffer, but there's an automated mode line update that instantly stepped on my change. Best advice I have is to spend some time staring at the definition of `erc-update-mode-line-buffer` and frowning mightily; it seems like some around-advice that plays with the values in the format spec might work well, but I ran out of time to play with it before I found something that actually does the job. HTH --

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 30-12-2020**:
After running into the same issue and running into my own answer, I dug a bit deeper and found a cleaner way to go about it.

I have a slightly more complex setup where a ZNC bouncer is involved, and I have multiple credentials for it, but the key setting that helped me was the following ERC setting

```
(setq erc-rename-buffers t)
```

Per the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/erc.html), `If non, nil, this will rename server buffers to reflect the current network name instead of IP:PORT`

So instead of having a bunch of servers named the same, this will make it so that ERC renames the buffers to the Network Name (which I think is provided by IRC networks themselves).

When using this, I think in your case you could then have a function that finds those buffers (as they would be named consistently the same) and renames them to your liking.

Hope it helps!

---

It's not ***the*** perfect solution, as I'm still looking for it and coming short... but what you can do is address the problem from a DNS perspective rather than an emacs one.

What I mean is, add local DNS entries such as:

```
whateverrandomserver => <also ip address of example.com>
```

This can be done by changing the file on `/etc/hosts` on *nix-based systems or in `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows-based systems. It's fairly trivial as those files are essentially space-separated mappings between domain names and IP addresses. Just add a new line with those entries and off you go.

Then basically have emacs connect to what is essentially the same server using different domain names, et voilà, you got yourself different buffer names for different servers.

If you ever do come across a proper emacs-only solution though, please do share!